# Removing array item from foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach, riot-games-api

I've fetched data from Riot Games API servers that supposes to give me all my champions points I've played with.

```
try {
    $poeni = $api->getChampionMasteries($sId);
}

catch {
    die("Failed." . $ex->getMessage());
```

Basically, now I have array elements that I'm trying to iterate with *foreach* loop, and put in HTML table.

```
<?php foreach ($poeni as $po): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$po->championId?></td>
            <td><?=var_dump($po->name . ", " . $po->title)?></td>
            <td><?=$po->championLevel?></td>
            <td><?=$po->championPoints?></td>
            <td><?=$po->chestGranted ? 'Da' : 'Ne'?></td>
            <td><?=$po->championPointsUntilNextLevel?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm no familiar with PHP, so pretty much I'm learning it. Apparently, my `$po->name . ", " . $po->title` is object, not an array so error I'm getting is **Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in**. I tried to access it's object with `$po[0]->{'name'}`, but getting error **cannot use object as array**. Everything else is working besides this.

Comment: Can you past here output of var_dump($po->name)  ?

Comment: @BenjaminKljuno you are calling the incorrect function.  Its var_dump() not vardump()